# Should I say "I don't have *an* enough information about this city"

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

In the following sentence should I need to add an article ('an') or I can write it without this article?

1. I don't have enough information about this city
2. I don't have **an** enough information about this city

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The '***enough***' in "**enough {something}**" is itself a *determiner* and thus does not need another determiner (article) in front of it.  It can have only an adverb, like "nearly".

Comment: yeah he's right you don't need the an

Answer (score 2):

Victor is correct, but it should also be mentioned that "information" is used in a plural form without any conjugation, much like "data." Therefore, even if we were to remove "enough:"

> I don't have an information about this city.

This is still incorrect. "Information" is understood to be a collection of things that you know, and therefore it is understood to be plural. Removing "an" or replacing "an" with "any" would make this sentence correct.